# Input field blurs when inline editing in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to do inline editing on a table of data (See the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yl6vziLQCMPh6boHsl1V?p=preview))

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr ng-repeat="data in dataset" >
  <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"  >

    <div class="key-block">
           <strong >{{key}}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="val-block" inline-edit="data[key]" on-save="updateTodo(value)" on-cancel="cancelEdit(value)">
        <input type="text" on-enter="save()" on-esc="cancel()" ng-model="model" ng-show="editMode">
        <button ng-click="cancel()" ng-show="editMode">cancel</button>
        <button ng-click="save()" ng-show="editMode">save</button>

        <span ng-mouseenter="showEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="showEdit = false">
            <span ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="edit()">{{model}}</span>
            <a ng-show="showEdit" ng-click="edit()">edit</a>
        </span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I can see in many places that we have to use a `.` in `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat` to avoid the scope issue. As I `dont know the key already` I am doing like `data[key]` for the model.
The input field blurs after I enter a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you described is normal. If you look closely you will see that both the input value and the directive are bound to the same object i.e `data[key]`. When you change the value of the text input the `model` get updated ultimately triggering a refresh of the directive and you are back to the "list" view.

One easy solution to fix this is to use an intermediate variable between the directive and the input value and update the model only when the save button is clicked. Something like that :

```
  //Directive
  scope.newValue = null;

  scope.edit = function() {
    scope.editMode = true;
    scope.newValue = scope.model;

    $timeout(function() {
      elm.find('input')[0].focus();
    }, 0, false);
  };

  //Template
  <input type="text" on-enter="save()" on-esc="cancel()" ng-model="newValue" ng-show="editMode">
```

You can see a modified plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/41hCVNmoSwDh0GunfqQ7?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for the solution.